# load html page in div without refresh when a link inside that div is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is what I need to get done:

Basically I have a 'map' with some 'dots' on it; when a dot gets clicked, I want to load another image instead with some other dots on it (dots are the links) without refreshing the page. One way of doing it was to get the div's dispaly:none, and when clicked, hide() current image (and dots on it) and fadeIn() the new one, but I don't want to load all the images every time the page is accessed.

The issue:

When doing it with plain PHP, it works perfectly fine: when it is on 'main.php' it opens image '1-25.png', when a link (dot) is clicked it opens the 'main.php?m=mapname' and opens 'mapname.png'. But, I want the page to stay still, and to have the content changed (without refresh).

I have first page with some navigation buttons, and a div where another page with links is loaded. I need to get the content inside the div changed when the link is clicked, without refreshing the browser. It works great if I am using any links or buttons outside the div, but as soon as I am trying to navigate inside the div, it does not work.

here is some code:
the index.php

```
<a href="1.php">First</a><br>
<a href="2.php">Second</a><br>
<a href="3.php">Third</a><br>
<?PHP
include ('div.php');
?>
```

the div.php

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}


        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#map').load('content.php');


        $('a').click(function() {
            alert(getQueryVariable("m"));

            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'content.php',
                data: 'm=' + getQueryVariable("m"),

                success : function(html) {
                    $("#map").html(html);

                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

and the content.php

```
if (!isset($_GET['m']) || empty($_GET['m'])) {
    echo "<div id=\"map1\" style=\"position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;\">
    <img src=\"./inc/pics/1-25.png\" style=\"position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; max-height: 500; max-width: 700;\">
    <a id=\"1\" href=\"index.php?m=l50\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 180; left: 180;\"></a>
    <a id=\"2\" href=\"index.php?m=r50\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 280; left: 410;\"></a>
</div></div>";
} else if ($_GET['m'] == 'l50') {
    echo "<div id=\"map2\" style=\"position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;\">
    <img src=\"./inc/pics/2-50-left.png\" style=\"position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; max-height: 500; max-width: 700;\">
    <a id=\"3\" href=\"index.php?m=l25\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 160; left: 110; \"></a>
    <a id=\"4\" href=\"index.php?m=tl25\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 140; left: 350;\"></a>
    <a id=\"5\" href=\"index.php?m=bl25\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 350; left: 350;\"></a>
</div></div>";
} else if ($_GET['m'] == 'r50') {
    echo "<div style=\"position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;\">
    <img src=\"./inc/pics/3-50-right.png\" style=\"position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; max-height: 500; max-width: 700;\" >
    <a id=\"6\" href=\"index.php?m=t25\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 150; left: 50;\"></a>
    <a id=\"7\" href=\"index.php?m=b25\"><img src=\"./inc/pics/reddot.png\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 380; left: 70;\"></a>
</div>";
}
```

**UPDATE\Fix**

I have deleted the 
   `$('#map').load('content.php');` 
from div.php, and then changed the click event to

```
    $('#map').on('click', 'a#1', function(event) {

        $("#map").load('map.php?m=l50');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the live page? I'm having a hard time imagining the visuals.

Comment: it is on my localhost.

Comment: You want to look into AJAX.

Comment: all it is, just a random image (map) with another image on top of it (dots), the image on top being a link. That link should load the same page, but with a different image in it. I want it done without the reload.

Comment: Martin, I did. it works fine with naviagation links, but it does not see any links loaded by the same AJAX

Comment: The problem is the event declaration. You should use `on()`. Try the snippet in my answer and see if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your current click event with this:

```
$('#map').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    $('#map').load($(this).attr('href'));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you! I modified it a bit, and it worked perfectly. Instead of "$('#map').load($(this).attr('href'));" I did a "$("#map").load('map.php?m=l50');" and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance! Just a question, though: `$("#map").load('map.php?m=l50');` will always load the same url. Is that intended?

Comment: No. At the moment I have made a click event for each link separately, ('a#1', 'a#2', etc) as I have only a few links. A bit later, I will dig into that, but at the moment the most importance is to get the images loaded without page refresh.

Comment: Well, if you're happy, then I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

If I was not wrong, it could be the link on the return content from ajax not working.
You should use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead to keep the click event still live after ajax request has been done

```
$('a').live('click', function(){ 
//do something
});
```

Edited:

> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead. To exactly match $("a.foo").live("click", fn), for example,
>   you can write $(document).on("click", "a.foo", fn). For more
>   information, see the .on() documentation. In the meantime, the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin can be used to restore the .live() functionality.
>   [live() removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

In case of after all does not work, you can put the script into the function in order to rebind them when ajax completed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if an `iframe` is quite reasonable for you to use.

Then you would need two `div`'s: one for the main map and one for the detail maps with the `iframe` on it. Then you would be able to refresh the content of the second div without refreshing the entire page.
It is also possible to execute javascript/jquery from inside an iframe on the outer parent page and vice versa.

This would be the way I would go for first. I am sure it is also possible without an `iframe`, but with a lot more programming work.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery .load function is built for this purpose (http://api.jquery.com/load/).  It will save you a lot of hassle.

Basicall the function loads content into your chosen selector e.g:

```
$("#myDiv").load('page_going_somewhere_else.php');
```

You can wrap this in a click event to fire when something is clicked like this:

```
$("a#myLink").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#myDiv").load(url);                          
});
```

and if you need to send data to your loaded page to check against you can send data like this:

```
$("a#myLink").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   $("#myDiv").load(url, {"myData":"myAnswer"});                            
});
```